# Custom drop-down panel with jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to find a jQuery solution for the following:

A generic drop-down control that:

- Looks like a normal select box when collapsed.
- Drops down a custom panel within which you can put anything

I'm *not* looking for a menu control, or a stylable select or list control. I need a control where the drop-down panel can house anything- not just a list of options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a fiddle that can be used as a base to get you going  http://jsfiddle.net/6zcRk/

**EDIT:**
Now a plugin: [jquery-easy-drop-down](http://appgrinders.github.com/jquery-easy-drop-down/)
(Yarin)

Comment: fairly easy to build one also

Comment: charlietfl- you made that just now?- that's pretty sweet! Thanks

Comment: charlietfl - I made this a [plugin](http://appgrinders.github.com/jquery-easy-drop-down/) - send me your name and I'll give you credit (my email's on the plugin page).