# drop down with checkboxes - is this possible with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I've a very difficult situation to handle... graphics my designer came up with is quite challenging for me to code :)

[image]

So this is a drop down (select) with check-boxes instead of normal options.

html looks like this:

```
                <select name="cat" id="control_1">
                <optgroup label="Mountain">
                    <option>Gudauri</option>
                    <option>Bakuriani</option>
                    <option>Svaneti</option>
                 </optgroup>
                 <optgroup label="Seaside">
                    <option>Batumi</option>
                    <option>Kobuleti</option>
                    <option>Kvariati</option>
                    </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Capital">
                    <option>Tbilisi</option>
                </optgroup>
                </select>
```

I'm already using this plugin for rewriting other SELECT elements, so it would be awesome to be able to utilize same code base and just build on that :) -> http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Any help with ideas or examples will be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some fiddles in this thread that just got converted to a plugin that would be fairly easy to adapt to your situation

[Custom drop-down panel with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548618/custom-drop-down-panel-with-jquery)

EDIT: appears the demos for constructing dropdown from a select got removed from above post, I edited post and put back this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6zcRk/

Comment: Interesting, but I don't like how plugin has no fallback strategy... I believe it's much better practice to make drop-down as select first (in case user has js disabled for example) and than rewrite it into anything else... right? :)

Comment: @sandrophoto  just noticed demo that is created from select got removed from that post, I just put it back there as well as above. For your case you could use a class on LI to change checkbox as an image and not need a real checkbox